# putting multiple functions under 1 main function

Tags: javascript

I'm using this line of code quite a bit:

`.hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);`

Is there a way to make this a function or variable (pretty sure can't use a var, but thought I'd ask) so I can call it as needed?  I know I could just copy/paste, but it clutters up the code to see that over and over.

I tried:

```
function properDisplay() {
    .hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it a plugin:

```
$.fn.properDisplay = function(){
  return this.hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
};
```

Usage:

```
$('#SomeElement').properDisplay();
```

Comment: Thanks @Guffa.  That worked correctly.  It also helped me find another bug in my statement.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the element object as parameter

```js
function properDisplay(ele) {
   $(ele).hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function properDisplay(param) {
    $(param).hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

and then just simply call it like this:

```
properDisplay(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it into a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.properDisplay = function(whereToInsert, delay) {
  if (delay === undefined) delay = 1000;
  return this.hide().insertBefore(whereToInsert).fadeIn(delay);
});
```

Then:

```
$(".something").properDisplay("#placeholder");
```

In a plugin, `this` is a reference to a jQuery object, not a DOM element. It's conventional for plugins to return the jQuery object so that the function can be chained as is typical practice.